# Is there a different way how to send a HTTP "POST" request without using third party libraries using custom header and body?

Tags: ios, http, post, networking, request

I am trying to send a HTTP "POST" request for a web-service that should return a base64 encoded picture. This is an example HTTP request for the service:

[image: https://imgur.com/a/XTbVxEW]

I am trying the following:

```
func fetchPicture(username: String, password: String) {
    let url = URL(string: "https://myurl.com/download/bootcamp/image.php")!
    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    request.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    request.setValue(password.stringToSHA1Hash(), forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
    let postString = "username=\(username)"
    request.httpBody = postString.data(using: .utf8)
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
        guard let data = data, error == nil else {                                                 // check for fundamental networking error
            print("error=\(error)")
            return
        }
        if let httpStatus = response as? HTTPURLResponse, httpStatus.statusCode != 200 {           // check for http errors
            print("statusCode should be 200, but is \(httpStatus.statusCode)")
            print("response = \(response)")
        }
        let responseString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
        print("responseString = \(responseString)")
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

I am getting an error 401 Unauthorized, I don't actually know whether it is because my request is bad all together or just the login initials. It would be grand if someone could go over the code and tell me if it actually corresponds to the request example shown above.

Thanks!

Comment: Without knowing the exact format the server is actually expecting for the `Authorization` header, it is difficult to know whether `password.stringToSHA1Hash()` will suffice or not. But the `Authorization` header is required to carry 2 values - a type name, and the encoded credential data. You are not specifying any type name. When you get the 401 response, what value(s) are in its `WWW-Authenticate` header? That will tell you the type name(s) the server supports. Also, make sure to properly url-encode your `username` value in the `postString` so reserved characters are escaped properly.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Hello, the problem indeed was my hashing function was foul, it was giving me a wrong hash, algorythmical error. I will post the answer together with the correct SHA-1 hashing algorythm later when I can. I am on the 2 days lockdown for answering because I posted my question just yesterday. Thanks though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, I was using the CommonCrypto hashing function wrongly, I ended up using this instead:

https://github.com/apple/swift-package-manager/blob/master/Sources/Basic/SHA256.swift

And the SHA256 hash it returned was the correct one I needed, maybe this might help someone in the future.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing I notice is that you aren’t setting the request HTTP Method:

```
request.httpMethod = “POST”
```

Comment: Sorry, that was some mishap when I was editing the post. This line of code I have and it is in the original post now, updated, thanks! However the problem really is somewhere else.

Comment: @CtiborŠebák yea, I figured that wouldn’t solve it, but just wanted to make sure!